# TCP socket security on the local network

Tags: arp, sniffing, spoofing, network-security

I have a server displays the led status from the client. The client turns the led on or off with the command from the server. Packets are encrypted with AES. but i'm thinking about a scenario as follow :

an attacker can somehow enter the network and direct the packets to his own server using arp spoofing. In case he couldn't decrypt the packets, he can re-transmit these packets to my client and miss with led status.

How should I take precautions against such a situation?

The best solution I've found so far, change key and iv continuously. But I don't know how to do this efficiently.

Comment: This is not about programming. Protocol is not clear, so I cannot recommend any migration path.

Comment: try to secure your communication by using any pre-built ways, openSSL as an example